# Get custom post type in WordPress to load custom template

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I’ve created a custom post type in WordPress for events. My **index.php** page is based off the twenty Twelve theme in that it sets up The Loop and then passes off the rendering to a partial template:

```
<?php get_header();

if (have_posts()) {
    while (have_posts()) {
        the_post();
        get_template_part('content', get_post_format());
    }
}
else {
    get_template_part('content', 'none');
}

get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

However, when viewing an event post, `get_post_format()` just returns an empty string (I’d expect it to return `event` or similar) and in turn only the **content.php** template partial is loaded rather than **content-event.php** which is what I was expecting and actually want.

How can I make my event post type report `event` as its post format?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you confused [post formats](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats) and [post types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types). What you need here is [`get_post_type()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type).

Comment: I’m not sure. I just copied that from the Twenty Twelve theme. What is the different between a post type and a post format? Where does a post format come from?

Comment: Learned post formats are things like post, attachment etc. The above didn’t work (replacing `get_post_format()` with `get_post_type()` crashed WordPress believe it or not) I’m marking the answer as accepted as it guided me towards the solution (add a conditional to the **content.php** template using `get_post_type()`). Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by crash WordPress? Set [`WP_DEBUG`](http://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG) to `true` to get the actual error.

Comment: If you want a specific template for your `event` post type, you can alternatively create a file called `single-event.php` to be used as [template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy).

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
if(get_post_type()):
    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_type() );
else:
    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
endif;
```